# Regex replace an email

Tags: java, regex, replace

In my SQLite database I have a composite key that comprises of an email and a tutorial name (it's an e-learning app) such as **sonop@us.ac.zaTutorial 1** or **randomperson@gmail.comTutorial 3**. I'm having problem splitting the two when I use them later on. I want to get the tutorial (**Tutorial 1**) and email (**sonop@us.ac.za**) separately. Seems straightforward but I'm struggling?

Here'se what I've tried so far:

```
    String Key = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("key"));
    String email = Key.replace("^(.*)(Tutorial)(\\s)(\\d+)$", "$1");
    String Tutorial = Key.replace("^(.*)(Tutorial)(\\s)(\\d+)$", "$2$3$4");
```

However when I use print statements later on, nothing is replaced or changed. Any ideas? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: If you're problem has been resolved, feel free to accept the most suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with regex, then something like this should work:

```
    String pattern = "(.+)(Tutorial\\s\\d+)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String[] s = { "sonop@us.ac.zaTutorial 1",
            "randomperson@gmail.comTutorial 3" };
    for (String str : s) {
        Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `replaceAll` (and not `replace`) if you want to work with regexps. But in this case I'd recommend that you simply do:

```
int i = input.lastIndexOf("Tutorial");
String email = input.substring(0, i);
String tutorial = input.substring(i);
```

If you really want to go with regexps, I'd recommend something like

```
String key = "^(.*)(Tutorial \\d+)$";
String email = input.replaceAll(key, "$1");
String tutorial = input.replaceAll(key, "$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
System.out.println("sonop@us.ac.zaTutorial 1".replaceAll("^(.*?@[^A-Z]+)([A-Z]\\S+\\s*\\d+)$", "$1 $2"));
System.out.println("sonop@us.ac.zaTutorial 1".replaceAll("^(.*?@[^A-Z]+)([A-Z]\\S+\\s*\\d+)$", "$1"));
System.out.println("sonop@us.ac.zaTutorial 1".replaceAll("^(.*?@[^A-Z]+)([A-Z]\\S+\\s*\\d+)$", "$2"));
```

**Output:**

```
sonop@us.ac.za Tutorial 1
sonop@us.ac.za
Tutorial 1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nR7cO4/1)

Group 1 contains the email id and group 2 contains the string `Tutorial` and following number.